# Multiline find and replace wrapper with wildcard inside

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm trying to put a wrapper around a bunch of fields that already exist.

#### I want to convert this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.LastName)
</div>
```

#### To this:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty green with Regex, but here's the closet I came so far to [matching on the pattern](http://www.regexr.com/39hde):

```
<div class="editor-label">(.|\r\n)*?(</div>)(.|\r\n)*?(</div>)
```

Then it could replace with something like this:

```
<div class="field-group"><div class="editor-label">(.|\r\n)*?(</div>)(.|\r\n)*?(</div>)</div>
```

But that obviously doesn't work.  But the idea would be wrapping around the matched value.

When I use the replace in Notepad++, it replaces it with the string `(.|\r\n)*?(</div>)` instead of the matched value.

Can I do a wildcard search and replace that persists the original wildcard matched value?
Or somehow wrap the contents another way?

**Note**: I'm using Notepad++, but I'd gladly use any other text editor that has this kind of functionality.

Comment: Notepad++, right? Not the stock Notepad included in Windows?

Comment: What are you replacing the match with? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Excellll, I want to basically add a wrapper around content that matches the provided description.  If it matches, I want to take the whole text block and add content before and after it.

Comment: Got it. I was more interested in the string you are using to replace the match in Notepad++. That is, what do you have typed in the `Replace with` field?

Comment: @Excellll, added update

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the regex substitution engine which is exposed through the Find and Replace feature in notepad.  But first, you'll need to be a little familiar with how any regex is able to find and replace text.

### Some Regex Info

**Capturing Groups**:

- `(ABC)` - **capturing group** - Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group
- `(?:ABC)` - **non-capturing group** - Groups tokens together *without* creating a capture group
- `\n` - **backreference** - Matches the results of a previous capture group (ex. `\1`)

**Substitution Symbols**:

- `$&` - **match** - Inserts the entire matched text.
- `$n` - **capture group #n** - Inserts the results of the specified capture group (ex. `$1`)

---

### How to Wrap with Regex Substitution

To wrap any text, first right a regex query to find it.  Then replace that entire string with a new one composed of the text you'd like to wrap around it and the original matched text by using `$&`.

Here's a [**Demo in RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/3a3r4):

[image: Wrap Text]

Here's an **Example with JavaScript**:

```js
var wrapMe = 'WrapMe';
var wrapped = wrapMe.replace(/WrapMe/g, "<wrapper> $& </wrapper>");
console.log(wrapped); // <wrapper> WrapMe </wrapper>
```

To wrap the entire regex query with a substitution

---

### How to Insert with Regex Substitution

Here's a [**Demo in RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3a3r7):

[image: Insert Text]

Here's an **Example with JavaScript**:

```js
var insertMe = '<wrapper>Replace</wrapper>';
var inserted = insertMe.replace(/(<wrapper>).*(<\/wrapper>)/g, "$1 Inserted $2");
console.log(inserted); // <wrapper> Inserted </wrapper>
```

---

### The Problem at Hand

Knowing all that, the problem at hand in Notepad (or anywhere else) should seem rather trivial:

Here's a [**Demo in RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/3a3ra):

**Search For**: `<div class="editor-label">((.|\n)*?(<\/div>)){2,2}`
**Replace With**: `<div class="field-group">\n$&\n</div>`

You can pull up the Find and Replace with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image: Problem Screenshot]

> **Note**: Remember to set the search mode as Regular Expression and also that notepad typically requires `\r\n` to find a newline instead of just `\n`